# How can I simulate chromatograms and spectra?

Tags: mass-spectrometry

Is there a tool which allows to generate simulated chromatogramms and spectra and export it into a mzML file? There is e.g. [`psims`](https://github.com/mobiusklein/psims) which allows to write mzML on a low level. However I was not able to find a high level tool which allows to define chromatogram shapes via a e.g. a GUI.

Comment: What is the purpose to generate fake chromatograms and spectra?

Comment: It's about testing if the library I'm using is not manipulating the data by mistake. I'm using `pyopenms` which uses [OpenMS](https://github.com/OpenMS/OpenMS) under the hood. I could not find tests for the lib yet.

Comment: OK, I found the tests: https://github.com/OpenMS/OpenMS/tree/develop/src/tests I'm trusting the devs that they are doing their job properly :)

Comment: Sorry, I do not know that programming stuff but you can "make" chromatograms yourself in MATLAB by summing up several Gaussians as a function of time. Also add some random noise. Note that the peak width increases linearly with time. You can also explore PeakFit as GUI for chromaatographic peak analysis.

Comment: Instead of using the word "fake" use the word simulated. Fake has a negative connotation and there are tons fake papers out there.

Comment: The words "fake"/"mock" are the correct ones in the software development domain. However I understand your concerns w.r.t. "fake" in the chemistry/research domain :)